# Python Global variable clearance

Tags: variables, spyder, global, clearance

I am confused with the behavior I observe in python (Spyder IDE). I clear all global variables (and delete all variables anyway)

```
globals().clear()
```

I could check that nothing remains with

```
print(globals())
```

also the variable t does not exist in the workspace.
but then I execute the following

```
import numpy as np
t = np.empty([105,1])
```

but now my newly created variable t has values that it had previously, they are definitely not random or placeholders, but precisely what it had before. How is that possible? If I restart Spyder, then it would become truly random upon the first run.